# Overload == for class to compare with std::string

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to overload `==` operator for my class so that I can compare a property of my class with a std::string value. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Message
{
public:
    string text;
    Message(string msg) :text(msg) {}
    bool operator==(const string& s) const {
        return s == text;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string a = "a";
    Message aa(a);
    if (aa == a) {
        cout << "Okay" << endl;
    }
    // if (a == aa) {
    //    cout << "Not Okay" << endl;
    // }
}
```

Now, it works if the string is on the right side of the operator. But how to overload `==` so that it also works if the string is on the left side of the operator.

Here is  [link](https://ideone.com/Ctyl7Q) of the code in ideone.

Comment: Most recently asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260752/how-to-multiply-integer-constant-by-fraction-object-in-c/53268504#53268504
Use a friend function to define the global binary operator.

Comment: note: in the ctor-initializer it should be `text(std::move(msg))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator with `std::string` as first parameter needs to be outside the class:

```
bool operator==(const std::string& s, const Message& m) {
    return m == s; //make use of the other operator==
}
```

You may also want to make `Message::text` `private` and declare the operator as `friend` in the class.

Comment: I would use `return m == s;` to ensure consistency and avoid logic repetition.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good idea, I changed it!